# how to open Home Activity from any another Activity without using Intent

Tags: android, button, android-activity, back, launching

In a interview someone asked me this question. Suppose there are 4 activities in application. He wants back button to work normally on first three activities(i.e. going to previous screen on back button press); except the last.

He wanted that, when he press back button on fourth activity(screen), user should go to Home Activity(Starting Screen or first screen). But the contents on Home Activity should be same when user went from first screen to second screen. So I think, I can't use Intent, as it will create new instance of Starting Activity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> He wanted that, when he press back button on last activity(screen), user should go to Home Activity(Starting Screen or first screen).

The interviewer should be interviewing for his or her own replacement, if (s)he thinks that hacking the BACK button this way is a good idea.

> So I think, I can't use Intent, as it will create new instance of Starting Activity.

Add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` or the combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to the `Intent` used with `startActivity()` to bring up your "home activity". Either will cause the existing "home activity" instance to come to the foreground. If you want all other activities to be destroyed, use the second approach (`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`).